# Python: Division by Larger Number

Tags: python

```
print 1/50
```

results to a rounded zero: 0

```
print float(1/50)
```

once again returns zero but as a float.

What syntax I should be using to get a right result (0.02) using only stock modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
print float(1/50)
```

Performs an integer division of 1/50, and then casts it to a float. This is the wrong order, since the integer division has already lost the fractional value.

You need to cast to a float **first**, before the division, in one of these ways:

```
float(1)/50
1./50
```

Answer (score 6):

When you write `print float(1/50)`, Python first calculates the value of `1/50` (ie. `0`) and then converts it to a float. That's clearly not what you want.

Here are some ways to do it:

```
>>> print float(1)/50
0.02
>>> print 1/float(50)
0.02
>>> print float(1)/float(50)
0.02
>>> print 1./50
0.02
>>> print 1/50.
0.02
>>> print 1./50.
0.02
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/50
0.02
```

This is on by default in Python 3